# Listing/setting directories that make & C++ search for header files

Tags: c++, include-path

I have a project with which I'm learning how to use make with C++ (which I'm also learning).
I've managed to get GCC 4.6 installed with mac ports, and have installed the Boost libraries with homebrew.
My issue now is that my project's includes to boost aren't working with this error:

> fatal error: boost/test/unit_test.hpp:
>   No such file or directory

I guess the version of GCC I'm using (the one installed by mac ports) is not using the standard search path for include files? The file in question (boost/test/unit_test.hpp) is definitely on my system, at /usr/local/include.
Is there some way that I can list the directories that are being searched in make & by GCC, so that I can verify that this is indeed the problem?
Cheers for any & all help,
   Doug.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem. How did you solve it please?

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc -v -x c -c /dev/null
```

will give you, among other things, the path used for searching include files.  You can modify this path with arguments to gcc.  The main one being `-I/another/path/to/use` but you may want to read the [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options).